# packages for time series forecasting

Tags: forecasting

Are there appropriate packages for timeseries (analysis and forecast) in python?

And what methods they include?

there are in R the forecast package with includes many functions. Is there any same package like this in Python?

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting question.

I found there are 2 packages in Python:

```
Pandas and you can use for forecasting:
Regression
Some EMA
See more: http://pandas.pydata.org/

Statmodels you can use for forecasting:
AR
ARMA 
VAR
See more: http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/
```

However I don't know if all of forecasting package from R you can find them in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `pandas` package out. http://pandas.pydata.org/. Maybe this is what you are looking for